# Finding out the element of degree $p$ in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

For a prime $p$, define $ζ_{p^3} = e^{\frac{2πi}{p^3}}$.

Then for the field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^3})$? May I please ask how to find an element of degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$? I am simply ask for an explicit example here, better with a general formula involves $p$.

I know that this question may be quite related to Galois theory. But I am asking for a solution that without using Galois theory, at least not to use it explicitly because I have not learnt it. However, I think the idea of Galois theory may help. Could someone please tell me how to deal with that? Thanks.

**P.S.** Also I am interested in the general case: for any integer which is not less then $2$, consider  $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$, how can I see if I have an element with degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$ here?

If it is really hard to do it without the usage of the Galois theory, may I please just ask for a "Claim and justify" answer which simply point out which element is of order $p$ and prove that its order is $p$. Many thanks!

Comment: The degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{p^3}$ is $\varphi(p^3) = p^2(p-1)$. As $p$ divides this, on expects the existence of such an element.

Comment: Using Galois theory it is easy to show that such an element always exists. Without it I don't see a good way right no, at least not without just dropping random facts about cyclotomic fields on you...

Comment: Consider the degree of extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{3}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is $p^3-p^2$. The subfields are precisely the fixed field of subgroups of the Galois group which in this case is abelian of order $p^3-p^2$. So it has a subgroup of order p(p-1). By fundamental theorem of Galois theory if H be the subgroup of order p(p-1) then if we call k to be the fixed field of H then $[k:\mathbb{Q}]$=p.

Comment: @ayberk I do know the fact that about the degree of this field. But with out the explicit usage og Galois theory, could you please tell me $p$ divides the degree of the minimal polynomial implies the existence of element of degree $p$? And if possible, could you please give an example?

Comment: @Bemte I know some facts about cyclotomic fields, could you please tell me something more? I would try to understand.

Comment: @PropositionX Your latest claim is false. In general it is not true, that there is an element of order $p$ if $p$ divides the degree of the field extension. It is true in your case however, because the Galois group is cyclic. So it will be hard to show without Galois theory, because the Galois group is precisely what makes you see this fact.

Comment: @MooS So if possible, could you please just use the idea of Galois theory to explain or just give an example? That is, could you please simply find such an element and prove it is of order $p$?

Comment: I guess giving an explicit example for $p \neq 2$ is quite a messy computation, maybe not even doable by hand. For $p=2$: $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$ contains $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @MooS So is the idea of computation also comes from Galois theory? If I may understand, could you please explain how can we deduce that the elements of degree 2 are these 2 elements? Is it possible to find a general formula for such an element?

Comment: Have you ever computed $\zeta_8$? If so, you would not ask this question.

Comment: Yes, one of the results from Galois theory is how to compute these elements. You have to know the structure of the automorphism group of your field (which in this case is the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$). Already that is not that easy for general $p$ and $n$. Then you have to find a certain subgroup, take sums of roots of unities with respect to this subgroup, etc. So in short: Without any Galois theory you might be able to drop an element of order $p$ in a special case and not tell how you got it, but the general case is difficult, to say the least.

Comment: @Bemte: Actually you only have to cover the case $n=2$, because for $p \neq 2$, we know that there is a unique subfield of degree $p$ over the rationals and this is already contained in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^2})$. But it is still impossible to give a description of such an element, since we do not even have a description of a primitive root mod $p^2$, i.e. we do not have a description of the subgroup, which corresponds that subfield...

Comment: @MooS I will ask for a specified case only consider $p=3$. If possible, could you please have a look?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252875/finding-out-an-element-of-degree-p-in

Comment: @Bemte https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252875/finding-out-an-element-of-degree-p-in Now I am considering only a special case, but any arbitary $n$, so if possible, could you please have a look?

Comment: Don't ask the same questions many times, tks https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252875/finding-out-an-element-of-degree-p-in

Comment: @user1952009 It is not the same question at all. The scope is entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer expected, as it uses Galois theory, but it is a little long for a comment.
Finding an element of order $p$ in the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^3})$ is equivalent to finding a sub-extension, say $E$, of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. To find it, one needs first to look at its Galois group (if want to avoid it, you can work also with embeddings from $K$ to $\mathbb{C}$), which in this case is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, which I'll denote by $G_p$.

(ASIDE: A class represented by $a \in \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to the automorphism of $K$ determined by sending $\zeta_{p^3}$ to $\zeta_{p^3}^a$.)

For the prime $p=2$, this group is of order 4, and indeed is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

(ASIDE: this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2^{r-2}\mathbb{Z}$ when 3 is replaced by $r$.)

This is basically why the case $p=2$ is easy.

For $p>2$, $G_p$ is cyclic, generated by the product of image, say $a$ of the generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ (you need to know that this group is cyclic) in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ with the class of $1+p$.

(ASIDE: You can show easily that the class of $1+p$ generates a sub-group of order $p^2$ in $G_p$.)

Hence the subgroup say $H_p$ generated by the product $a(1+p)^p$ is of size $p(p-1)$, hence is of index $p$. Now, fundamental theorem of Galois theory tells you that the elements that are fixed by $H_p$, say $E$, is a sub-field of K of degree $[G_p:H_p]=p$.

As we work in characteristic 0, this field can be written as $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^3})$. Then, of course, this $\alpha$ is of degree $p$. This partly answers your question. Of course, it is not easy to find such an element explicitly.

One should check by hand that a sum of the element $\zeta_{p^3}$ over all classes  in $G_p/H_p$ should work, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once I learn Galois theory I will try to understand it.